# How to get Related result from mysql encoded string

Tags: php, mysql, search, encoding

I am encoding string using `$encodestr = base64_encode($str);` and store this string in a database. Now I want to search this string using `MATCH(title) AGAINST('$title')` but I can not get any result. I have stored many project titles in myself encoded form. Now if the user wants to search "funny product" then I have used `MATCH(title) AGAINST('$title')` for search it works before encoded but after encode it does not work.
Can anyone help me how to get the most related result using PHP and MySQL from an encoded string in myself?

I have used this query:

```
$titleTomatch = base64_encode($title);

$rel_query ="select v_id ,title,image_med_url,v_view, MATCH(title, des)
AGAINST('$titleTomatch') as score  from v_data where MATCH(title,des)
AGAINST('$titleTomatch') or cat = '$cat' and block =0 and del =0  order by score desc limit 15";
```

Comment: Encode the $title in base64_encode and then compare with TITLE from database...base64_encode is a hash function and hash function get decoded with lot of time and effort

Comment: @Satty  i m using this query "select v_id ,title  MATCH(title, des) AGAINST('$title') as score  from v_data where MATCH(title,des) AGAINST('$title') order by score desc limit 10;" can u help me how can i search for related item in fast way.

Comment: Keep in mind that `x OR y AND z` is treated as `x OR (y AND z)`; I ssupect this is not what you wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So when you are matching a title against all encoded titles which are stored in db just encode your title then feed into sql.

```
$titleToMatch = base64_encode($title);
```

Then use query like `MATCH(title ) AGAINST('$titleToMatch')`

Comment: @javarocks it'd be helpful if you can add a sample data in your post for which this is not working..

Comment: please check post i have added query

Comment: `FULLTEXT` index will _not_ work against any form of encrypted/encoded/etc string.  `FULLTEXT` needs to 'see' words.

Answer (score 0):

Won't work.

`FULLTEXT` index will *not* work against any form of encrypted/encoded/etc string.  `FULLTEXT` needs to 'see' words.

That is, you cannot make `MATCH` work in any fashion with strings mangled via base64_encode.

Nor will `LIKE` or `REGEXP` work, at least not all the time.  (One-third of the time the bits will align correctly, and those *might* work.)